# Exposing the API end-points for CRUD Operations in Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack, laravel-api

How can I expose api-end points for the CRUD controllers used for backpack so that I can reuse the operations in the controllers without having to code new ones, while adding necessary api features like JSON, authentication modes

Comment: The endpoints themselves are exposed. The routes get created like routes normally do, you could hit these routes with an ajax request and should be able to interact with them just fine. That said, you may have at least 2 obstacles. 1) CSRF Token middleware for those routes, you'll need to supply a valid token from the page, or disable the middleware. 2) The response you get will likely be html in at least some cases.

Comment: Are you using Backpack v3.X or v4?

Comment: I am using Backpack v4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Backpack routes work like API end-points for XHR requests, so adding a header `HTTP_X-Requested-With` with a value `XMLHttpRequest` causes backpack to return with JSON